# Поправить в regex

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Ребята, поправьте, пожалуйста, регулярное выражение ip address, может можно красившее написать.

```
p = '^10.0.11|12|15|21|25|31|35|40|41|45.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$'
pat = re.compile(p)
if pat.search('10.0.20.2'):
  print "OK"
else:
  print "NOT OK"
```

Answer (score 3):

Я бы слеши перед точками проставил бы, а то получается, что 10a0b11c2 пройдет:) Ну и скобочки поставил бы, а то выражение 12 пройдет или "15."
С другой стороны, Ваше выражение пропускает что то вида "15.:255" - я думаю, это не совсем то, что хотелось бы.
Если я все правильно понял, что Ваше выражение должно быть такое

```
'^10\.0\.(11|12|15|21|25|31|35|40|41|45)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$'
```

если дадите больше айпи для тестов, могу уточнить выражение.

Comment: ip будут из диапазона 10.0.(11|12|15|21|25|31|35|40|41|45).1-250
исключать буду 10.0.20.1-5

Comment: а что подразумевается под "исключать буду 10.0.20.1-5" ? Оно и так не попадает в Ваш диапазон.

Comment: согласен, немного тупонул)

Comment: `"15.:255"` Не пропускает. `(?:...)`  - это не захватываемая группа

Answer (score 3):

Проверка ip впринципи:

```
re = /^(?!\.)((^|\.)(\d|(([1-9]|1\d|2[0-4])\d)|25[0-5])){4}$/
```

Именно ваша задача:

```
re = /^10\.0\.([1-4][15]|12|40)\.(\d|(([1-9]|1\d|2[0-4])\d)|25[0-5])$/
```

Comment: эта регулярное выражение не подойдет т.к. т.к. нужно именно из точного совпадения 10.0.(11|12|15|21|25|31|35|40|41|45).1-250

Comment: обновил ответ

Answer (score 0):

Добавлю свой вариант для регулярного выражения для проверки ip

```regex
^(?:1?[0-9]{1,2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(?:\\.(?:1?[0-9]{1,2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])){3}(?::(?:[0-9]{1,4}|[1-5][0-9]{4}|6[0-4][0-9]{3}|65[0-4][0-9]{2}|655[0-2][0-9]|6553[0-5]))?$
```

Comment: Отформатируйте регулярку